# How do I convert ASCII code to ASCII glyph in python 3

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to convert a list of strings like u0032 u0033 to their glyph equivalent in python. I know there has to be a built in function for this but I can't find it.

input = 0032 or u0032 or \u0032

print(function(input))

output: 2

Comment: In the title you should replace ASCII with Unicode. What you are asking is not limited to ASCII

Comment: Note: "Glyph" is a strange word for this case. Glyph imply an image, so it is something that font do (and you can extract an image of every glyphs [but some, e.g. control codes in ASCII]). Technically you are still sending 0x32. Just hidden on video card chip (or in graphical terminal program) there is the translation of code to glyph. And if you connect to a Braille console, you still do not have the normal glyph of two (but still a two).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve this. This is the simplest:

```
def u_chr(s):
    if s[:2] == '\\u':
        s = s[2:]
    elif s[0] == 'u':
        s = s[1:]
    return chr(int(s, 16))

print(u_chr("u0032"))  # 2
print(u_chr("u00C4"))  # Ä
print(u_chr("u5678"))  # 噸
```

This uses the [ast library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
import ast

def u_chr(s):
    if s[:2] == '\\u':
        t = f'"{s}"'
    elif s[0] == 'u':
        t = f'"\\{s}"'
    else:
        t = f'"\\u{s}"'
    return ast.literal_eval(t)
```

This uses [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html):

```
def u_chr(s):
    if s[0] == 'u':
        s = '\\' + s
    elif s[:2] != '\\u':
        s = '\\u' + s
    return s.encode('latin_1').decode('unicode_escape')
```

In these examples I have left out parameter checking and error handling. If, e.g., you want `None` to be returned when an exception would be raised, just replace

```
    return ...
```

with

```
    try:
        return ...
    except ValueError:
        return None
```